# Unable to connect to key vault using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

I am following this [part in the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault#redeploy-to-azure-app-service-and-use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources) for integrating key vault with spring boot.

We have everything setup for using Managed identities (application.properties and dependency in pom) and since it doesn't run in local development, I am testing it by deployment, however I am getting these errors in the log stream:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException:/home/tomcat/lib/azure.appservice.jar (No such file or directory)`

and

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to configure KeyVault property source`

`java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: Http://xxx.xx.x.x.x`

**EDIT: turned out I had a typo error in the client-id property.**

Answer (score 0):

make sure the application has permissions to get and list secrets in access policies of your key vault and also check the jar files are added properly.

Edit the `src/main/resources/application.properties` file so that it has the following contents, adjusting the values for your Azure subscription.c

```
azure.keyvault.client-id=<your client ID>
azure.keyvault.client-key=<your client key>
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.keyvault.tenant-id=<your tenant ID>
azure.keyvault.uri=https://contosokv.vault.azure.net/
```

[image]

After adding `azure.keyvault.tenant-id=<your-tenant-id>` in the file:

[image]

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault) and follow this [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/release/2.3.2/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-sample#azure-key-vault-secrets-spring-boot-starter-sample) code